# ASP.NET MVC ViewUserControl: How do I load its scripts dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewusercontrol

I have a ViewUserControl that will be used in some pages in my site, but not all.

This ViewUserControl requires a javascript file, so I would like to have the script reference added automatically to the head session of the pages that are using this ViewUserControl, is that possible?

I tried to add a content control to it, but looks like it is not allowed.

I could also add the script tag straight into the ViewUserControl's .ascx code, but then I will have the script reference added N times if I have N of such controls in a page.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the code-behind of the ASCX, register your script reference (or block). I just answered a similar question explaining how to do this:

[How to best control loading of multiple javascript files in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732854/how-to-best-control-loading-of-multiple-javascript-files-in-asp-net/733411#733411)

With this technique, you can have the same control on the page multiple times, yet still include the script only once (and only on pages that actually include the control).